# JSON extract Facebook Graph API iOS xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm in need take the data that passes facebook me with the scores of the players, but I can not return the values that are within the braces in xcode.

Example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "927806543903674", 
        "name": "Renata Gabi"
      }, 
      "score": 333, 
      "application": {
        "name": "Player 2", 
        "namespace": "quemsoueubiblico", 
        "id": "303489829840143"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "user": {
        "id": "964974026864922", 
        "name": "Player 1"
      }, 
      "score": 230, 
      "application": {
        "name": "My Game", 
        "namespace": "quemsoueubiblico", 
        "id": "303489829840143"
      }
    }
]
}
```

In android I use this

```
...
jgame = jObject.getJSONArray("data");
...
score = jgame.getString("score");
name = jgame.getJSONObject("user").getString("name");
photo_id = jgame.getJSONObject("user").getString("id");
```

for ios in xcode, I was trying this, but is not working

```
myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSData *jsonSource = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                         [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.escoladepsicanalisekoinonia.com/teste/index.html"]];
    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                      jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
        NSString *score_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"score"];
        NSString *name_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *id_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@.........);
        dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      score_data, score,
                      name_data, name,
                      id_data, id,
                      nil];
        [myObject addObject:dictionary];
    }
```

I am not able to adjust the "data" facebook graph, and get the subclasses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` item in your JSON sample is an array, but you're not taking this into account in your code. Try this:

```
myObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSData *jsonSource = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.escoladepsicanalisekoinonia.com/teste/index.html"]];
id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                  jsonSource options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSArray *data = [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"data"];

for (NSDictionary *dataDict in data) {
    NSString *score_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"score"];
    NSDictionary *user_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSString *name_data = [user_data objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *id_data = [user_data objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@.........);
    dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  score_data, score,
                  name_data, name,
                  id_data, id,
                  nil];
    [myObject addObject:dictionary];
}
```